# Declaração de Variável com Valor Default na Procedures

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, declaração-de-variável, delphi-10

Teria como declarar uma variável com um valor padrão na Procedures?

```
procedure TfrmManutencao01.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  lPriAber : Boolean = True;
begin
.
.
.
end;
```

sei que assim como está acima o Delphi não aceita.

Comment: E qual a necessidade de ser no corpo do procedimento?

Comment: Eu só queria saber pois um amigo me pediu e eu estou em um local sem o Delphi instalado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondendo diretamente a pergunta: Não, `Cannot initialize local variables`.

O que você pode fazer é declarar a variável antes da seção `implementation`

```
var
  FormX    : TFormX;
  lPriAber : Boolean = True;
```

Dessa forma podera usa-a no procedimento.

Se por acaso não for alterar seu valor, pode-se localmente declara-la como constante.

```
procedure TfrmManutencao01.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
const
  lPriAber : Boolean = True;
begin
..
end;
```

Ainda não consegui entender a necessidade.

Comment: Era só para tira uma duvida...Obrigado!